Dexie returns duplicated object after manually deleting the database and re-populate it. It only happens when you do not refresh the page
I have a feature on my website to allow users to delete Dexie database manually. I just found that after the database is deleted and gets re-populated without refreshing the page, it will return duplicated data, even though the chrome inspector shows there are no duplicated rows in the IndexedDB. However, the issue goes away when you refresh the page right away after database deletion.
This is the function to clear the database:
function deleteDB(){
  await db.delete();
  await db.open();
}


And this listener should run on deleting the database:

export class MySubClassedDexie extends Dexie {
    constructor() {
      playlists: "++id,*competitionIds",
     });
   }
}


db.on("populate", async () => {
  await db.playlists.bulkAdd(defaultPlaylists);
});

It looks like the only way to prevent duplicated data without refreshing is to use await db.playlists.bulkPut(defaultPlaylists);.
Can anyone figure out why?

This sounds like a bug. Would you be able to reproduce it in and post an issue on dexie repo?

@DavidFahlander Going to post it on your repo, but check out this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dexie-issue-forked-djwxz6 . The data keeps adding up on each click.
